# xcode : update icon badge daily

Tags: iphone, xcode, calendar, uilocalnotification

I looked at many pieces of codes but didn't get solution yet,

I simply need to get my app icon badge updated daily with some calendar (not gregorian) number of the day.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would code it, but if you were going to submit such an app to the app store, apple wouldn't approve it. Apple's strict review guidelines can be frustrating, and like in this case, they limit functionality of your apps. Sorry :(

Comment: it's a little part of my app, don't worry, there is all ready similar apps approved.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can't use repeating local notifications, because you want to specify an application badge number. Therefore you have to use one local notification for each day scheduled at midnight and with the appropriate badge number.

Because you can only schedule a maximum of 64 local notifications, you have to queue the notifications at each application launch.

This code isn't tested, there might be problems with daylight saving times, etc. (Works on iOS 4.2 or later, using ARC)

```
- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSUInteger startingDayAfterToday = [application.scheduledLocalNotifications count];
    NSArray *localNotifications = [self localNotificationsStartingOnDayAfterToday:startingDayAfterToday];
    NSArray *newScheduledNotifications = [application.scheduledLocalNotifications arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:localNotifications];
    [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:newScheduledNotifications];
}

- (NSArray *) localNotificationsStartingOnDayAfterToday:(NSUInteger)startingDayAfterToday {
    NSMutableArray *localNotifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:64 - startingDayAfterToday];
    for (NSUInteger i = startingDayAfterToday; i < 64; i++) {
        // Create a new local notification
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.hasAction = NO;

        // Create today's midnight date
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; // Could be other calendar, too
        NSDateComponents *todayDateComponents = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSDate *todayMidnight = [calendar dateFromComponents:todayDateComponents];

        // Create the fire date
        NSDateComponents *addedDaysComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        addedDaysComponents.day = i;
        NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:addedDaysComponents toDate:todayMidnight options:0];

        // Set the fire date and time zone
        notification.fireDate = fireDate;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

        // Set the badge number
        NSDateComponents *fireDateComponents = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:fireDate];
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = fireDateComponents.day;

        // We're done, add the notification to the array
        [localNotifications addObject:notification];
    }

    return [localNotifications copy];
}
```